# FlutterでAnimatedListのitemBuilderに適用されるアニメーション速度を変更したい

Tags: flutter, dart

FlutterでAnimatedListのitemBuilder内でSizeTransitionを使ってListの要素の追加時と削除時にアニメーションしているのですが、より早いアニメーション(アニメーションの開始から終了までを早くしたい)にするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?

今はSizeTransitionのデフォルトのアニメーションなのですが、これを変更するにはどうすればいいですか?

```
Widget _buildItem(Host host, Animation<double> animation) {
  return SizeTransition(
    sizeFactor: animation,
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(host.name),
      trailing: PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder: (context) {
          return [
            PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Edit"), value: host),
            PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Delete"),
                onTap: () {
                  AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder =
                      (context, animation) {
                    return _buildItem(host, animation);
                  };
                  hosts.removeAt(host.own_index);

                  _listKey.currentState!.removeItem(host.own_index, builder,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
                }),
          ];
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnimatedListState`の`insertItem`と`removeItem`の`duration`パラメータに短い時間設定をしたらできませんか。

提示されたコードであれば、`_listKey.currentState`が`AnimatedListState`のオブジェクトに当たると思います。

提示されたコード上は、削除を200msに設定してありますが、それを50msとかに設定するとか。
`insertItem`部分のコードは提示されていないけど、そちらも似たような実装で実現できると思います。